# CSS transition-delay not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to make an image make itself bigger when hovering over it. However the `transition-delay` property does not seem to work. The image is loaded by an `object` tag, however I have also tried using the `img` tag.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhJNV/embedded/result/)

```
<div id="c_a">
<object data="https://lh6.ggpht.com/Rr2X9m8HrCIGJrOKG3MOr9pRYERaa4yBLWUTeB6YNgJVlseJSMIbFWDc9nX6O2Y9HeWRf-2qL1gy0TInmKtKfRIBAJVPK4eglImapFb9=s660" type="image/jpg"></object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#c_a object{
  transition: width 1s linear 2s, height 1s linear 2s;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s linear 2s, height 1s linear 2s;
  -o-transition: width 1s linear 2s, height 1s linear 2s;
  -moz-transition: width 1s linear 2s, height 1s linear 2s;
}
#c_a object:hover{
  width: 300%;
  height: 300%;
}
```

Comment: Post the code too. :) By the way nice first post! ;)

Comment: What you have [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/WhJNV/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give initial width and height of 100% to begin with.

```
#c_a object{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   // transitions..
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhJNV/1/)

Comment: Thank you. But do you care to explain why it doesn't work without specifying width and height?

Comment: @LcSalazar did you wait for the delay? ;) Tested in Chrome & Firefox

Comment: @user3661754 Browsers get weird about animating to or from `auto`; the CSS WG was concerned about the complexity of nested transitions all going to/from `auto` where the transitions were causing circular recalculations.

Comment: Didnt work in my case, most of the rules wait 250ms, but not all

Answer (score 83):

I had a problem where transition-delay was not working
It's important to put `transition-delay` **after** `transition` property!

```
transition:
transition-delay:
```

Comment: Pretty friggin relevant to half the people landing on this question via google.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Very easy to overlook.

Comment: This is the real solution! The selected answer makes no sense.

Comment: this for some reason breaks the delay

Comment: I would love to upvote this answer because it solved my problem, but really don't want to change the upvote count past 69

Comment: so good that even against Mozilla's examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

Answer (score 3):

My `transition-delay` wasn't working either, but corbacho's solution did not do it for me. However, I discovered that if I change `transition` to `transition-duration` then it works!

```
transition-duration:
transition-delay:
```

By the way, the order doesn't make a difference for me on this.

Comment: best answer here imo - not need to worry about rule order or wierd hacks